# Separate a list into differently named lists

Tags: python, string, list, split

I'm currently learning really basic python as a side project during my PhD. And to apply what I'm learning, I wanted to automate a basic sudoku grid solver.

This story begins with a list...

```
lines=['53xx7xxxx', '6xx195xxx', 'x98xxxx6x', '8xxx6xxx3', '4xx8x3xx1', '7xxx2xxx6', 'x6xxxx28x', 'xxx419xx5', 'xxxx8xx79']
```

And I'd like to get something that looks like:

```
line1=['5', '3', 'x', 'x', '7', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
line2=['6', 'x', 'x', '1', '9', '5', 'x', 'x', 'x']
...
```

etc...

What I've been struggling with is looping the whole thing in a very efficient way.
For now what i've done is creating each list by taking each elements and then split them with a small function I saw somewhere on a tutorial website.

For each element in the list, i repeat that, I just need to copy paste  and get line1 to line9 lists.

```
def split(word): 
    return [char for char in word]  

line1=lines[0]
line1=split(line1)

line2=lines[1]
line2=split(line2)
...
```

It works, but it does look not efficient at all. I did not find any beginner-friendly anwser yet for this specific question.

Do you guys know a better way to handle multiple list generation inside loops?

Thanks for your attention,
Enjoy your day!

(PS: i'm french, sorry for any english related mistakes!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate through your list using a for-loop, split the element using your split method and store the split elements in a new List.
By iterating through that new list you can access the splitted lines again.

Here is a little example. The first print command will print out the entire List. The second one a single element.

```
def split(word):
    return [char for char in word]


newList = []
for line in lines:
    line = split(line)
    newList.append(line)

print(newList)
print(newList[0])
```

Comment: I think that will do! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Python provides direct typecasting of string into list using list(). You can use this function instead:

```
def split(word): 
   return list(word)
```

Comment: Thanks! This will be useful !